# IDEA Java swing GUI form Jtable. table model is overwritten by auto generated code

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Some tutorials say I can use Jtable like this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(myModel); // where myModel is a table model
```

But how can I do that if the IDEA GUI Form automatically generates the code?
I can't use the constructor function to pass the model.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by mark on 17-11-8.
 */
public class StudentManager {
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JTextField textField4;
    private JTextField textField5;
    private JPanel myPanel;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JButton sumButton;
    private JButton averageButton;
    private JButton sortButton;
    private JButton button5;
    private JTable table1;


    public StudentManager() {

        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StudentManager");
        frame.setContentPane(new StudentManager().myPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `JTabel#setModel` to change the model after the `JTable`s been instantiated. I would highly recommend that you avoid form editors until you have a better understanding of the basic operations of the API, while useful, form editors can encourage bad habits when comes to GUIs

Comment: Please check ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/JTableSample.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Your generated code :

```
JTable table = new JTable();
```

Later, your code to set the model :

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addRow(...*your data*...);
table.setModel(model);
```